# How to count / mail every time a duplicate value has been made?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to get myself send an email every night at 0:01 with a cronjob when a certain value has been filled in duplicate the last 24 hour.

What I have so far is this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, detection.number FROM detection INNER JOIN(SELECT number FROM detection GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2)temp ON detection.number = temp.number WHERE DATE(date_submit) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY number";
```

Every day I want a list of duplicates that has been filled in the last 24 hour so when a number is filled in as duplicate and has been filled in a few days ago, I want that number in the list and offcourse I want the duplicates which has been filled only the last 24 hours.

Any idea how to create this?

Maybe with an extra column with a counter of number of duplicates?

Or can I make this one happens with only a mysql query?

Here's some sample data to hopefully understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Table name = detection
number - date_submit
111 ----- 2016-02-29
222 ----- 2016-02-29
333 ----- 2016-02-29
111 ----- 2016-03-01
333 ----- 2016-03-01
111 ----- 2016-04-02
111 ----- 2016-04-02
444 ----- 2016-04-02

When I run the cronjob on 2016-04-03 00:01 am I want to search through whole the database for numbers which are filled in yesterday, e.g. 111 and 444.
And with these numbers, I want a search for duplications of that numbers and put all of the found duplicates in an e-mail, e.g.
111 ----- 2016-02-29
111 ----- 2016-03-01
111 ----- 2016-04-02
111 ----- 2016-04-02

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: Provide table structure, sample data and expected results.  I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: I have just added some sample data, hopefully it's a little bit clear now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * 
from detection D1
where exists 
(Select 1 
 from detection D2 
 where date_Submit >=now()-interval 1 day 
   and D1.Number = D2.Number)
```

Comment: unfortunately thast doesn't did the trick, I get all the records of the last 24 hour, also those who weren't double.
What do you mean with the "1" in "Select 1 from detection D2 "
Also I think I wasn't clear enough in my question but I also want those in the e-mail which number exists in the table 3 times or more so only duplicates aren't interesting, only which exists 3 times or more. My my apologies for this ... :-(

Comment: Gotta admit I'm baffled by the comment followed by accepting of answer.  Must have put you on a more correct track I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try to get he numbers having count > 1.

```
SELECT 
    number, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    detection 
WHERE 
    DATE(date_submit) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
ORDER BY 
    number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: because I than get only 1 record of the duplicates, e.g. 3 records with the same number result in 1 record and I want to see all the 3 records. With the inner join I can accomplish that.